# NodeJs/TestCafe : FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, heap-memory, testcafe

While running my testscripts in node v14.6.0, i'm seeing the below issue.

Options tried -

1. I tried to  increasing the Node Heap Size , but no luck
   export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
2. added the below in package.json
   "start": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 start",
   "build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build",

<--- Last few GCs --->

```
[65847:0x108000000]   415572 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 8189.2 (8204.8) -> 8188.5 (8204.8) MB, 4380.9 / 31.8 ms  (average mu = 0.131, current mu = 0.003) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[65847:0x108000000]   420034 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 8189.5 (8201.8) -> 8188.7 (8203.0) MB, 4450.9 / 28.9 ms  (average mu = 0.071, current mu = 0.002) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
```

<--- JS stacktrace --->

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x1012b7fd5 node::Abort() (.cold.1) [/Users/vn0lka6/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/node]
 2: 0x1000a3fa9 node::Abort() [/Users/vn0lka6/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/node]
 3: 0x1000a410f node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/Users/vn0lka6/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/node]
 4: 0x1001e57f7 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/vn0lka6/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/node]
 5: 0x1001e5793 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/vn0lka6/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/node]
 6: 0x100383775 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/Users/vn0lka6/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/node]
 7: 0x10038523a v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [/Users/vn0lka6/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/node]
 8: 0x100380909 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/Users/vn0lka6/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/node]
 9: 0x10037e1a1 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/Users/vn0lka6/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/node]
10: 0x10038ca3a v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/Users/vn0lka6/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/node]
11: 0x10038cac1 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/Users/vn0lka6/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/node]
12: 0x10035a487 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/Users/vn0lka6/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/node]
13: 0x1006d8758 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/vn0lka6/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/node]
14: 0x100a4faf9 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit [/Users/vn0lka6/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/node]
15: 0x100a148bd Builtins_AsyncFunctionEnter [/Users/vn0lka6/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/node]
16: 0x3367850aaa95 
Abort trap: 6
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The flag is `--max-old-space-size`, not  `--max_old_space_size`.